# Angular md-icon tag not importing the source from its url to the browser

Tags: angularjs

I have used the following tag from angular material design to display a button icon. But i dont get the icon on the webpage. can anyone please help me with this.

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="bower_components/material-design-icons/editor/svg/production/ic_insert_link_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

The path is right though and scripts are attached to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the wrong attribute to set your icon source.

According to the docs:
https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.icon/directive/mdIcon

You should be using `md-svg-src` attribute if you want to specify a source path for your icon - `md-svg-icon` is used to specify as a string name from the internal cache.

For Example:

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
    <md-icon md-svg-src="bower_components/material-design-icons/editor/svg/production/ic_insert_link_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

If the icon still does not appear, check if the source path is relative to the location of your html document.